# Connection to derby database refused

Tags: java, netbeans, derby, embedded-database

I am learning Java and trying to put together a simple App containing a few jTables connected to database that can be updated etc. To do this I have created a database with a few tables through Netbeans which I understand (and wish) to be embedded in the final distributable app.

I am following the Programming Knowledge tutorials on Youtube to create most of the GUI. Everting is OK as long as I open the Services tab on Netbeans and manually right-click my database(testDB) and click Start Server. Then when I run the following code I get a successful connection:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try{
            //Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            //Open a connection
            String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/testDB";
            String u_name = jTextField1.getText();
            String p_word = jPasswordField1.getText();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/testDB",u_name,p_word);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Details Correct - Connection established");
            Close_me();
            Open_Table_GUI(u_name,p_word);


        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }        
}
```

However if I run that code WITHOUT manually clicking on start server I get the following:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error       connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused.
```

I have read the apache documentation and due to my level of inexperience I am not getting anywhere.

I have also checked out the answers to similar connection questions on here but again I can't seem to relate the issue in a way that works.

The ultimate goal for me is to have an app I can distribute to run on windows machines that will have the database/tables all included individually editable etc. I would hope to eventually create a database that resides on a shared drive and each individual can connect to automatically - but that's way down the line for now.

My request here is that someone can help me understand what I need to change in my code so that the "Start Server" is automatically done.

Thanks in advance for nay response.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys so I found code that seems to work for me from a question asked on here by [LMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4012073/ims)

```
private void setup(){
    try{
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:sheet;create=true","test","1234");
        statement=connection.createStatement();
    }

    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnf){
        System.out.println("class error");
    }

    catch(SQLException se){
        System.out.println(se);
    }
}
```

If anyone cares to link me to a reason why this in fact works that would be great, I'm assuming the Embedded driver doesn't go through the port and just looks within the project??

Anyway initially this seems to be solved!!

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Server setting i.e.
-username and pwd in your program 
and check that did you start the Derby server and is it listening at port 1527?

Comment: The username a pwd are correct, everything works ok as long as I start server in the Netbeans environment - my question is how do i start this programmatically? OR as in my found answer above, where can i find out about the difference between the Embedded driver and the driver I was using, ClientDriver. I assume the difference is obvious but how does the JVM/Derby interpret these differently?

Comment: I think the best source of information about the differences between Embedded and Client/Server Derby is in the Derby manuals. Start here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/